# Mass of people its/his/their

Tags: possessive-pronouns

In a phrase where the subject is "*mass of people*", should I use "*its*"?

e.g.

> *A mass of people and its flag.*

***Mass*** is an abstract word, so it sounds strange to me to use ***their***; but I'm not sure.

EDIT:

Seems that according notional agreement I should use ***their***

but

If the mass of people act like a cohesive body, e.g.

> *a mass of people is/are united in its/their flag*

Is this a *situational agreement* and is the use of plural forms wrong?

Could you help me?

Comment: I would say "a mass" is an unusual word to use to quantify people. Not unheard of, necessarily, but it has an odd feel to it.

Comment: @Robusto I know, but It's a sample that I need to clarify the explained doubts.

Comment: I don't think it's unusual to use the word for people. Here's a dictionary definition: mass  2.  a large number of people or objects crowded together. "a mass of cyclists"  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mass

Comment: @chasly It's usually used in more concrete (like crowd, throng) than abstract (like population, nation) situations, though. And 'mass/crowd of people' doesn't collocate too well with 'its flag'.

Answer (score 5):

The fragment does not strike me as idiomatic or even meaningful in the first place. But ignoring that for a moment, yes, you should go with [notional agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synesis).

A lot of people and their flag. A variety of people and their flag. A mass of people and their flag.

(Oh, and *his* is right out. A mass is not a he. Ever.)

Comment: Reading your link now I have another doubt. If the mass of people act like a cohesive body. e.g. a "mass of people is/are united in its/their flag"... Is this situational agreement and the use of plural forms wrong?

Comment: The use of "their" and the plural would never be wrong referring to a "mass", "crowd " or similar. It might sometimes be less appropriate than "it's" if you want to emphasise the unity.